# What's the best way to create a feed page in iPhone?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to create a feed page in my iPhone application and the functionality is very similar to the Newsfeed in Facebook with the only difference being the comments and likes are shown on the same feed page itself rather than navigating to a different view in Facebook.

**Constraints / Challenges**

> 1.In my Feed page, I have a set of
>
> {
>
> [Feed item card]
>
> [a Comment / Like Card]
>
> },
>
> {
>
> [Feed item card]
>
> [a Comment / Like Card]
>
> }
>
> 2.There is another challenge where the comments are shown using ellipsis if it's longer and the user has to tap on the comment to expand it and view it completely. When you tap to expand all the below rows (including next feed card) should position accordingly.
>
> 3.Height of feed card alone is 353px and the height of the comment card
>   is variable based on the number of comments and their length.

I implemented this using UITableViewController where each row will have a {feed card and comment card} and it's working perfectly fine and however I have a question and a problem.

**Question**

1.Am I using the right approach here ? When the user scrolls down, I'm supposed to load more records from the server / core data and put them below. Will there be any performance bottlenecks if I have more than say 200 entries esp since the row height is always > 500px?

**Problem**

2.Say I have 5 records on the page and when I scroll down the table view is not painting the next {feed card and the comment card row} for a few seconds and then it suddenly appears. I have used Table views in several other projects but never seen a similar behavior which triggered the previous question.

Is there another approach rather than using UITableView ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm right now using 1 section and x number of rows. Would it make much difference if I change it to x sections and 2 rows (1 for the feed card and the other for the comment card) ?

Comment: Further research shows that scrolling becomes sluggish when reloadData method is called on the table view. Any helpful pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

If the table view cell is larger than the screen this can lead to performance issues during scrolling. I would strongly recommend to make the cells smaller. Maybe you can split the info in several cells.

To the problem: Do you reload the table view on a thread which is not the main thread? The UI always have to be refreshed on the main thread.

Comment: I refresh the table view after data load by posting a notification on the main queue (by calling performSelectorOnMainThread) which will be picked by the main thread. So it's not threading issue. I'm afraid I can't change the designs either so is there a better approach for implementing this rather than using Table views. Maybe using UIScrollView but then I have to manually re-position all the sub-views when there is a height increase on the comment cells.